# Rcpp function call from function in the same cpp file

Tags: rcpp

Hi i have this rcpp file :

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]

int ricercamin (NumericVector p, NumericVector u, int n1){

   int trovato=0;
int m;
int i=0;
while(trovato==0 & i<n1){
    if(u[i]==1){
        trovato=1;
        m=i;
    }
    else{
        i++;
    }
}
for(i=0;i<n1;i++){
    if(p[i]<p[m]){
        m=i;
    }
}
return m;
}

}

// [[Rcpp::export]]

NumericMatrix trai (NumericMatrix weigth, CharacterVector src, CharacterVector rn){

int n=weigth.nrow();
NumericVector potenziale[n];
NumericVector predecessore [n];
NumericVector insieme [n];
int i,j,k;
 for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    j=ricercamin(potenziale,insieme,n);


.....
}
```

The error is : 
use of undeclared identifier 'ricercamin'

How can i solve this ?

it seems like it does not found the function but the function is in the same cpp file and the declaration is before the call of the fun.

Comment: In C++ you have to at least declare a function before using it. Either put `int ricercamin(...);` or the full function definition before its use `trai()`.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i've tried to put the declaration of ricercamin before using it in the function, now i modify the code in the question, the error is the same.

Comment: Maybe the signatures do not match? We cannot tell without a [mre].

Comment: ok i've just edited with more code, i can't put it all the code right ? so i try to put the necessary code to understand the error

Comment: sorry for my bad english

Comment: Please read the explanation at the provided link. You should not include all your code, but the *minimum* amount of code needed to *reproduce* the error. For this the code has to be compileable, but at the same time should not contain anything that can be removed without the error going away.

Comment: BTW, with `NumericVector potenziale[n];` you are creating an array of `NummericVector`s of size `n`. Is that what you want? In case you want a single `NumericVector` of size `n`, the correct syntax would be `NumericVector potenziale(n);`.

Comment: the errore is that the program didn't find the function, and the call of the function is in trai function. no more code for me is necessary to find the problem. if more code in necessary i have to put here all the code

Comment: yes i want a NumericVector of size n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example code does not compile since the braces are not balanced and a literal `....` within the source code is probably not want you want. Anyway, I have reduced your code to what I believe to be the heart of the issue:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int ricercamin (NumericVector p, NumericVector u, int n1){
    return 0;
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix trai (NumericMatrix weigth, CharacterVector src, CharacterVector rn){

    int n=weigth.nrow();
    NumericVector potenziale[n];
    NumericVector insieme [n];
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        j=ricercamin(potenziale,insieme,n);
    }
    return weigth;
}
```

Compiling this I do not get the quoted message but instead:

```
58911878.cpp: In function ‘Rcpp::NumericMatrix trai(Rcpp::NumericMatrix, Rcpp::CharacterVector, Rcpp::CharacterVector)’:
58911878.cpp:19:22: error: could not convert ‘(Rcpp::NumericVector*)(& potenziale)’ from ‘Rcpp::NumericVector*’ {aka ‘Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>*’} to ‘Rcpp::NumericVector’ {aka ‘Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>’}
   19 |         j=ricercamin(potenziale,insieme,n);
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                      |
      |                      Rcpp::NumericVector* {aka Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>*}
make: *** [/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:176: 58911878.o] Error 1
```

Now this error message tells me something useful: The function `ricercamin` expects a `NumericVector`, but I am giving it a *pointer* to a `NumericVector`. The correct fix depends on what the variable `potenziale` is supposed to contain. Since you mention "a NumericVector of size n" in the comments, you should use `(n)` instead of `[n]`, since the latter declares an *array* of `NumericVector`s:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int ricercamin (NumericVector p, NumericVector u, int n1){
    return 0;
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix trai (NumericMatrix weigth, CharacterVector src, CharacterVector rn){

    int n=weigth.nrow();
    NumericVector potenziale(n);
    NumericVector insieme(n);
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        j=ricercamin(potenziale,insieme,n);
    }
    return weigth;
}
```

This compiles without errors or warnings for me.

Comment: Thank You Very Very Very much ! the error is in declaration of      the correct declaration is     NumericVector potenziale(n) and not     NumericVector potenziale [n]